# Arguments in python function

Tags: python-3.x, function, arguments

How can I set as a function argument a slice of a region?. I am creating a function which takes a path and a region of interest for analyzing images. But I got stuck trying to set a region of interest as an argument to my function.
ROI = region of interest and it is like the following shape: 200:50,250:90 in a form of slice in a image array. I am using numpy to slice an image. For instance, `image[200:50,250:90]`

```
def imagen(path,ROI):
    """Return images and values related to the total amount of blood vessels in the image given
    a path and a region of interest of image"""
    img = cv2.imread(path,0)
    ROI = input('Introduce region of interes: ')
    print("Original image: ")
    plt.imshow(img, cmap ="gray")
    plt.show()
    clahe = cv2.createCLAHE()
    cl1 = clahe.apply(img[ROI]) #this line stops the execution due to the ROI format
    plt.imshow(img, cmap  ="gray")
    plt.show()
    t_lo = 45
    ret, thresh_lo = cv2.threshold(cl1, t_lo, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    print("Binarize Region of Interest")
    plt.imshow(thresh_lo, cmap = "gray")
    plt.show()
    pixel_total = thresh_lo.shape[0]*thresh_lo.shape[1]
    vessels = pixel_total - (np.count_nonzero(thresh_lo))
    print('Pixels corresponding to vessels: {0}'.format(vessels))
    print('Total percentage of vessels: {0:.2f} '.format(vessels/pixel_total))
    if vessels <= 0.07:
        print("Low percentage of vessels")
    elif vessels > 0.08 and vessels < 0.10:
        print("Medium percentage of vessels")
    elif vessels >= 0.10:
        print("High percentage of vessels")
    return vessels
```

The problem is the way the input is interpreting the ROI parameter. Any suggestion? The problem I am getting is the following: 
`IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indice`s